# How do I call the DoDirectPayment API call from Paypal

Tags: c#, paypal

First of all, this relates to a desktop application rather than an ASP .Net application.

I have added a web reference to my project, and have built up the various data objects such as PayerInfo, Address and CreditCard. The problem is though, how do i actually call the DoDirectPaymentRequest and pass in the objects? According to the documentation, i use a CallerService and ProfileFactory object, but i do not have these available to me.

Any ideas how i call the API from an EXE?

Regards

Comment: I bailed out in the end and used the PayPal NVP option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Service Reference instead of Web Reference in your project.
You should create an instance of ***PayPalAPIInterfaceClient*** or ***PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient***. After that you'll have an ability to call DoDirectPayment.

Example:

```
        DoDirectPaymentResponseType result;
        using (_client = new PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient())
        {

            DoDirectPaymentRequestType pp_Request = new DoDirectPaymentRequestType();
            pp_Request.Version = _version;
            pp_Request.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails = new DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType();
            pp_Request.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.IPAddress = ipAddress;
            pp_Request.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard = new CreditCardDetailsType();
            pp_Request.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber = CCNum;

            // ..FILL DATA

            // NOTE: The only currency supported by the Direct Payment API at this time is US dollars (USD).
            pp_Request.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.OrderTotal.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD;
            pp_Request.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.OrderTotal.Value = amountOfUSD;

            var dp = new DoDirectPaymentReq
            {
                DoDirectPaymentRequest = pp_Request
            };

            var credentials = new CustomSecurityHeaderType
            {
                Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType
                {
                    Username = _username,
                    Password = _password,
                    Signature = _signature,
                    AppId = ApiId
                }
             };

            result = _client.DoDirectPayment(ref credentials, dp);
        }
```